# Problem in paragraph shape

Tags: paragraphs

```
\begin{itemize}
\item \textbf{Equilibrium Condition} It represents the internal forces on the interface of component $A$ are equal but opposite to the forces on the interface of component $B$. As shown in Figure ???? and equation (?????) 
\end{itemize}



\begin{equation}
   g^{A}_{b}=-g^{B}_{b}
\end{equation}

The LM-FBS method extends Equation () by stating that the interface internal forces are denoted by some Lagrange multipliers shown in Figure (). Equation () shows the relation between the internal forces $g$ and the Lagrange multipliers. 

\begin{equation}
   g=B^{T}\lambda
\end{equation}

The matrix notation will form by substituting of equation () in () and by adding the compatibility condition of equation () as bellow:

\\***equation**\\

The presented system of equations is solved for the coupled displacements $u$. The derivation is below:

\\***eq*****\\
```

Comment: look at the new picture that i add, the paragraphs form is completely ruined. i do not know why? if i remove all this paragraph (The LM-FBS method...). nothing happen. problem still remain.

Comment: The code you've posted now compiles without any "paragraph shape" issues if I prefix it with `\documentclass{article}\begin{document}` and affix it with `\end{document}`.

Comment: not solved, as i said before i used the thesis package that i downloaded, in this package the  first page of the thesis, table of content, bibliograpgy and chapters wrote in different file. i did not have problem of paragraphing till in the middle of this chapter.

Comment: You've not given us any code to help you diagnose the problem.  The error image that you edited away says line 1229, but is quoting from your code image line 1227 and is complaining about the dot character after "y some Lagrange multipliers $\lambda$" and before "shown in Figure (). Equat".  Overleaf is reporting 39 errors.  You can't expect reasonable output if your code has errors in it.  (And the paragraph shape is that you've switched to a center justification.)

Comment: i have already share the part of the code that i faced problem! other 38 errors related to put some character like (\\****pic***\\) to remind me to replace them by equation or pictures. BTW if i remove that paragraph the problem still remain.

Comment: you have not provided code that shows the problem nor said what the problem is. You just say "problem with paragraph shape" but what problem do you get?    You should never have a blank line before `\begin{equation}` or you will get spurious white lines, and your lines `\\***equation**\\ ` will give an error for the first `\\ `  (no line to end) and an underfull hbox warning for the second `\\ `.  Please edit your question so that it shows the issue that you are asking about.

Comment: thanks to all of you guys. i fixed the problem.